# commit count calculation in git-describe

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Can anyone explain why git describe uses a count as "the number of commits which would be shown by git log tag..input" [from [git-describe(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-describe)]?

Conceptually I had thought git-describe used the number of commits since the tag as a monotonically increasing counter.  However, it seems it actually uses the number of commits reachable from 'input' minus those reachable by 'tag'.  Why is that?

In this particular case, I've created a release tag ("1.0.0") and then a patch release ("1.0.1") on a branch ("1.0").  I've merged up [see http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitworkflows.html] the branch changes to master.  Yet when I git-describe a more recent commit on master the count matches the output of git log tag..input.  I expected it to match git log --ancestry-path tag..input.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe `git describe --first-parent` should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`git describe` is a way to communicate the `HEAD` in a meaningful way. It is a simple answer to the question "Where am I in the history?" or "What version of the code is this?"

So, when you run the command it starts **where you currently are**, whether that is the tip of `master`, some other tag, or just a random commit. From this starting point it counts backwards through commits until it finds a tag. From there it will print the tag, number of commits counted, then the short commit number.