# Can I change how git-describe counts commits?

Tags: git, merge, git-describe

My question is related to [git describe: inexplicable commit count](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31852885/2314532) and [commit count calculation in git-describe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13568372/2314532), but not quite identical to either question. I've been developing on a feature branch in my current project, and I've been using `git describe` to get version numbers for the feature branch, using the recent tag and commit count to make a version number that I *thought* would be monotonically increasing. (E.g., my branch is currently 96 commits ahead of v1.1.0, so I've been turning `v1.1.0-96-g1234567` into "version 1.1.0.96" in the version I report to the user.)

Now, the master branch was recently tagged with v1.2.0, and I want to incorporate the changes made in version 1.2 into my feature branch. So I merged master into my feature branch, and I thought that `git describe` would yield `v1.2.0-1-g9876543`. But instead, I got `v1.2.0-97-g9876543`.

I understand why this is happening: as described in the Git manual, `git describe` is counting the commits produced by `git log v1.2.0..9876543` to produce the commit count (97, because my branch had 96 commits plus the one merge commit). But what I really want is to use the result of `git log --ancestry-path v1.2.0..9876543` instead, which shows just the merge commit and therefore would produce the `v1.2.0-1-g9876543` result that I was expecting.

Is there any way for me to change `git describe`'s behavior to use `git log --ancestry-path v1.2.0..9876543` instead of `git log v1.2.0..9876543`?

And, more importantly, **what is the benefit** of doing it the way `git describe` currently does it? If I write my own tool to produce the version numbering scheme I had been expecting, what will I lose by doing so?

BTW. here's a snapshot of the git repository history, so you can see visually what I just described. The `feature/cmdline` branch is the one I'm working on. (This history view is from the [Git Extensions](http://gitextensions.github.io/) tool on Windows, in case anyone's wondering.)

[image: brief snapshot of my feature branch]

Comment: To be fair, it *is* "monotonically increasing" (i.e. it never goes down) and that's at least something. But I do understand your misery. I jumped through the hoops and designed my own little algorithm to come up with the string (but had other priorities than you).